# Conditional heteroscedasticity vs iid hypothesis - McLeod-Li test

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, iid, arch

I am using the function McLeod.Li.test in the [TSA](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSA/TSA.pdf) package. According to the help file in R, this function “Performs the [McLeod-Li test](http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/aim/vita/pdf/SquaredRACF.pdf) for **conditional heteroscedasticity** (ARCH).”

However, it has been mentioned on page 50 of the book “Introduction to Time Series and Forecasting, Brockwell and Davis, 2nd edition” that the McLeod-Li test “can be used as a further test for the **iid hypothesis**”.

Question: Is it true to say that the McLeod-Li test can be used to check the “conditional heteroscedasticity” as well as the “iid assumption”? If not, which one is the correct null hypothesis?

Answer (score 2):

The McLeod-Li test can be used as a test of independence and it can also be used to test the hypothesis of no ARCH. In fact, the McLeod-Li test can be used as a general misspecification test against nonlinearity. See [Teräsvirta, Tjøstheim and Granger (2010)](http://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof%3aoso/9780199587148.001.0001/acprof-9780199587148), (pages 140-1 and 178-9).

You may find it useful to know that it is stated in [Patterson, and Ashley (2000)](http://books.google.ie/books?id=5V7HL7MegEkC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=mcleod%20li%20test%20null%20hypothesis%20iid&source=bl&ots=5BPFAL2iV8&sig=wY7kVwqfE9O8h4WKFU2akgMlEzY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=n_SGUZ_mNsWB7Qa_i4GABA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=mcleod%20li%20test%20null%20hypothesis%20iid&f=false), (page 40), that the null hypothesis is that the series is *i.i.d.*

I hope this information helps you, and rather than go into the particulars, I refer you to the aforementioned sources.

As a side note, it's worth mentioning that some tests can be used for a variety of purposes. For example, the BDS test can be used to test the *i.i.d* hypothesis, but it can also be used to test for the presence of non-linearity. I think this is a similar situation to the usage of the McLeod-Li test.